# Why is my javascript not interacting with webpage?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have created a random number generator and linked it with one of ID in my webpage using document.querySelector('#score-0').textContent = dice; But its not interacting with web page? [Not interacting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlFz5.png)

Here is the link to html css and js code in JSBIN : https://jsbin.com/lexojiyumi/1/edit?html,css,js,console

```js
/* eslint-disable */
var scores, roundScore, activePlayer, dice;
scores = [0, 0];
roundScore = 0;
activePlayer = 0;

dice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
console.log(dice);
document.querySelector('#score-0').textContent = dice;
```

```css
/**********************************************
*** GENERAL
**********************************************/

.final-score {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    top: 520px;
    color: #555;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: 'Lato';
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 160px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.final-score:focus { outline: none; }

#dice-1 { top: 120px; }
#dice-2 { top: 250px; }


* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
}

.clearfix::after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(62, 20, 20, 0.4), rgba(62, 20, 20, 0.4)), url(back.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    font-family: Lato;
    font-weight: 300;
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    color: #555;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 1000px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    overflow: hidden;
}

.player-0-panel,
.player-1-panel {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    height: 600px;
    padding: 100px;
}



/**********************************************
*** PLAYERS
**********************************************/

.player-name {
    font-size: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: 100;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

.player-score {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 80px;
    font-weight: 100;
    color: #EB4D4D;
    margin-bottom: 130px;
}

.active { background-color: #f7f7f7; }
.active .player-name { font-weight: 300; }

.active .player-name::after {
    content: "\2022";
    font-size: 47px;
    position: absolute;
    color: #EB4D4D;
    top: -7px;
    right: 10px;
    
}

.player-current-box {
    background-color: #EB4D4D;
    color: #fff;
    width: 40%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 12px;
    text-align: center;
}

.player-current-label {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #222;
}

.player-current-score {
    font-size: 30px;
}

button {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    color: #555;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    font-family: Lato;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 300;
    transition: background-color 0.3s, color 0.3s;
}

button:hover { font-weight: 600; }
button:hover i { margin-right: 20px; }

button:focus {
    outline: none;
}

i {
    color: #EB4D4D;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 15px;
    font-size: 32px;
    line-height: 1;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    margin-top: -4px;
    transition: margin 0.3s;
}

.btn-new { top: 45px;}
.btn-roll { top: 403px;}
.btn-hold { top: 467px;}

.dice {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 178px;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    height: 100px;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 60px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10);
}

.winner { background-color: #f7f7f7; }
.winner .player-name { font-weight: 300; color: #EB4D4D; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        
        <title>Pig Game</title>
  
      
     </script> 
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper clearfix">
            <div class="player-0-panel active">
                <div class="player-name" id="name-0">Player 1</div>
                <div class="player-score" id="score-0">43</div>
                <div class="player-current-box">
                    <div class="player-current-label">Current</div>
                    <div class="player-current-score" id="current-0">11</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="player-1-panel">
                <div class="player-name" id="name-1">Player 2</div>
                <div class="player-score" id="score-1">72</div>
                <div class="player-current-box">
                    <div class="player-current-label">Current</div>
                    <div class="player-current-score" id="current-1">0</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <button class="btn-new"><i class="ion-ios-plus-outline"></i>New game</button>
            <button class="btn-roll"><i class="ion-ios-loop"></i>Roll dice</button>
            <button class="btn-hold"><i class="ion-ios-download-outline"></i>Hold</button>
            
            <img src="dice-5.png" alt="Dice" class="dice">
        </div>
        
        <script src="project.js">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Delete `<script src="project.js">` from the jsbin and it will work, if thats what your asking.

Comment: is your project.js file in the same folder as the html file ?

Comment: What's `</script>` doing?

Comment: Your HTML isn't valid at first. You cannot have an unclosed tag `</script>` inside `<head>` and have it open before body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's that closing script tag at the end of the head? I recommend using a text editor which understands html, such as Atom. Check atom.io.

You could also declare your script in the head section and add the *defer* tag.

```
<head>
     ...
     <script src="your/script.js" defer></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `onclick` event in your `roll` button. Add that and it works:

```js
var scores, roundScore, activePlayer, dice;
scores = [0, 0];
roundScore = 0;
activePlayer = 0;

function roll(){
  debugger
  dice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  console.log(dice);
  document.querySelector('#score-0').textContent = dice;
}
//initial roll
roll();
```

```css
.final-score {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    top: 520px;
    color: #555;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: 'Lato';
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 160px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.final-score:focus { outline: none; }

#dice-1 { top: 120px; }
#dice-2 { top: 250px; }


* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
}

.clearfix::after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(62, 20, 20, 0.4), rgba(62, 20, 20, 0.4)), url(back.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    font-family: Lato;
    font-weight: 300;
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    color: #555;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 1000px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    overflow: hidden;
}

.player-0-panel,
.player-1-panel {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    height: 600px;
    padding: 100px;
}
/**********************************************
*** PLAYERS
**********************************************/

.player-name {
    font-size: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: 100;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

.player-score {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 80px;
    font-weight: 100;
    color: #EB4D4D;
    margin-bottom: 130px;
}

.active { background-color: #f7f7f7; }
.active .player-name { font-weight: 300; }

.active .player-name::after {
    content: "\2022";
    font-size: 47px;
    position: absolute;
    color: #EB4D4D;
    top: -7px;
    right: 10px;
    
}

.player-current-box {
    background-color: #EB4D4D;
    color: #fff;
    width: 40%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 12px;
    text-align: center;
}

.player-current-label {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #222;
}

.player-current-score {
    font-size: 30px;
}

button {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    color: #555;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    font-family: Lato;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 300;
    transition: background-color 0.3s, color 0.3s;
}

button:hover { font-weight: 600; }
button:hover i { margin-right: 20px; }

button:focus {
    outline: none;
}

i {
    color: #EB4D4D;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 15px;
    font-size: 32px;
    line-height: 1;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    margin-top: -4px;
    transition: margin 0.3s;
}

.btn-new { top: 45px;}
.btn-roll { top: 403px;}
.btn-hold { top: 467px;}

.dice {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 178px;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    height: 100px;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 60px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10);
}

.winner { background-color: #f7f7f7; }
.winner .player-name { font-weight: 300; color: #EB4D4D; }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper clearfix">
            <div class="player-0-panel active">
                <div class="player-name" id="name-0">Player 1</div>
                <div class="player-score" id="score-0">43</div>
                <div class="player-current-box">
                    <div class="player-current-label">Current</div>
                    <div class="player-current-score" id="current-0">11</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="player-1-panel">
                <div class="player-name" id="name-1">Player 2</div>
                <div class="player-score" id="score-1">72</div>
                <div class="player-current-box">
                    <div class="player-current-label">Current</div>
                    <div class="player-current-score" id="current-1">0</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <button class="btn-new"><i class="ion-ios-plus-outline"></i>New game</button>
            <button onclick="roll()" class="btn-roll"><i class="ion-ios-loop"></i>Roll dice</button>
            <button class="btn-hold"><i class="ion-ios-download-outline"></i>Hold</button>
            
            <img src="dice-5.png" alt="Dice" class="dice">
        </div>
```